# Should i invalidate View?

Tags: android, animation, view

if inside our onCreate-method we will try to run next code:

```
    //imagine that view's shape is a line
    View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
    view.setPivotX(0f);
    view.setPivotY(0f);
    view.setRotation(90f);
    //then again rotation
    view.setRotation(-45f);
```

which way will the view be turned? to 4.5 hours?
No. (1.5h) Don't know why, but when i try to do second rotation,view position after first rotation will be droped.Main question - why? I set totally the new position in space for view, and it's just...ignored by the every next same type settings. It's android's bug or i should invalidate changes of view's position? And if it is, how i can do it?

Comment: `view.setRotation(-45f);` will take effect no matter how many times you called `setRotation` before

Comment: @pskink yes. but -45f relative default position of view, not relative current position

Comment: because the method's name is `setRotation`, not `rotateBy`